# C# Socket Receive to String

Tags: c#, sockets

Following [this guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463947/Working-with-Sockets-in-Csharp) I wrote the following function:

```
public string ConnectToHost(string ip, int port)
{
    Socket socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    IPAddress host = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
    IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(host, port);

    socket.Connect(ipep);

    byte[] msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("<Client Quit>");
    int msgSend = socket.Send(msg);

    byte[] bytes;
    int byteRecieve;

    String msgRecieved = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes, 0, byteRecieve);
    while (socket.Available > 0)
    {
        byteRecieve = socket.Receive(bytes);
        msgRecieved += Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes, 0, byteRecieve);
    }

    socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    socket.Close();

    return msgRecieved;
}
```

But I get error

> Use of unassigned local variable 'bytes' and Use of unassigned local variable 'byteRecieve'

on the lie of code

```
String msgRecieved = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes, 0, byteRecieve);
```

Removing the `Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes, 0, byteRecieve);` from the line and only have `String msgRecieved;` gave the same error but within the `while` loop.

How do I get this function to return the recieved bytes as string?

Comment: _"Following this guide"_ - please don't. It's horrible, common for CodeProject "tutorials". It shows that the author lacks basic socket and string encoding knowledge, and this code is broken beyond repair. Please find another tutorial, or pick up a good book on networking.

Comment: Because _"I copied this code off the internet, fix my compiler errors"_ isn't really a question we're looking forward to on SO? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's true that you are using those variables without them being assigned, no? That's not allowed because it's unclear what that means. In this case you can make it work by saying:

```
    byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
    int byteRecieve = 0;
```

When you have solved those compiler errors, which have nothing to do with sockets, you'll find that using `Available` underestimates the amount of data that's incoming. It is almost never useful.

Also, you'll find that `Unicode` encoded strings cannot be broken up at arbitrary boundaries so this does not work either. Use `StreamReader`.

You probably should keep looking for a different tutorial. Most are very broken. TCP is very hard to get right.

Answer (score 0):

Look at these two lines of code:

```
int byteRecieve;
```

and

```
String msgRecieved = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes, 0, byteRecieve);
```

In the first line you declare `byteRecieve`, but do not assign a value to it. In the second line you make use of it. Since you have not assigned a value to it you get the error message.

Since you do the right thing inside the `while` loop, you can simply delete the second line above....

Also

```
byte [] bytes;
```

should become something like

```
byte [] bytes = new bytes[256];
```

or similar. Again your version merely declared `bytes` to be an array of byte, but did not allocate/assign that an actual array value to it.